# When using Axios, array gets data filled in, but empty on page refresh

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

```
 let vm = this;
    axios.get("https...")
    .then(
      function(response) {

        if (response.status == 200) {
          vm.code = response.data.code;
          vm.eventDetails = {
            name: response.data.name,
            start_time: response.data.start_time,
            end_time: response.data.end_time,

            ticket_details: null
          };
        }
      },

      axios
        .get(
          "...")
        .then(function(response) {

          if (response.status == 200) {       
            vm.eventDetails.ticket_details = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
     vm.eventDetails.ticket_details.push(response.data[i]);


              );
            }
          }
        })
    );
```

The array ticket_details gets filled in with data whenever it wants, since the data it is not persistent in it as when I refresh the page, the array goes back to be empty. I will attach few screenshots to make it clearer.

[image: Array with elements in]

[image: Array gets empty on page refresh]

Comment: You have to store that array in `localStorage` if you want it to persist over refreshes

Comment: are you using html5 mode ? using hash tag in ulr or not ?

Comment: also its prone to break as your expecting the promises to finish in order.

Comment: I have tried to story it through the localStorage and it does not fix it..